# How to fetch all objects in Laravel from an s3 directory according to tags applied?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, tags

I am storing images in a folder called `gallery` in my s3 bucket. For testing when I store the images in it, I tag them using this laravel code

```
Storage::disk('myBucket')->put($image_path, $image, ['Tagging' => 'foo=bar', 'visibility' => 'public']);
```

I checked manually in my s3 bucket,and I can see the images added with a tag of Key=foo, and Value=bar

Now I am trying to find a way in which I can query all the images in the `gallery` folder which have a certain tag, but I am not sure how to do this in Laravel. Any ideas?

Also I want to tag the images like `tag=animal,food,forest` and so on, depending on what the image contains. So that it is easier for me to fetch all images tagged with `food` in them. Is this possible, or do I need to think of a different solution?